# Eclipse doesn't start android app in emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm right at the beginning of android programming.

I created an AVD that works just fine when launching via the AVD-manager.
I also "created" a hello-world app as a little test.

When I try to run the app as an android app, nothing happens. No output in the console, emulator doesn't start (or launchs app when already started), no message, nothing.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: import the project in anothet adt bundle your project will run

Comment: Does the "Android Device Chooser" window pop up after you tell Eclipse to run your app as an Android app?  What ADT (Android Developer Tools) version are you running?

Comment: Nothing pops up at all.

Comment: I just downloaded this package (it said it's all in there): http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: What do you see when you click on the Android Device Manager Icon?  Do you see the AVD you created listed?  How are you telling Eclipse to run your project?  I right-click on my project then go to "Run as" then "Android Application".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you but, during our android lab sessions some computers had a slimier problem. How it was fixed is by doing the following:

1. Next to the "Run as" button, there is a small arrow, click it.
2. Select "Run configurations".
3. On the left, double click "Android Application".
4. There should be 3 tabs appearing on the right (Android, Target, Common)

   - Under "Android", browse and select the project you want to run.
   - Launch Action: select "Launch Default Activity".
5. Click on "Target" tab.

   - There should be an AVD table with the Android virtual devices you created through the manager. In case there isn't, hit refresh or click on "Manager" to make sure you have created it and then refresh again.
   - if there is an AVD, it should appear with a small check box on the left side of it, click it and then click on "Run".

This fixed the issue for most students, hopefully it will in your case as well. If not then I hope someone can answer it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think its because u created a project with a blank activity. so when the app starts it doesn't have anything to do..

to solve the issue just add an activity, intent and  a category to your manifest file and run

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, Give your SDK path in Eclipse as Windows->preferences ->Android->SDK Location

here you give your sdk path.

Comment: I don't even have a point named SDK-location under Android in that window. I downloaded this package: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html The only thing that sounds similar is called NDK.

Comment: I'm running under Windows (ADT version 21.0.1.201212060302) and I don't have an SDK path option under Windows->Preferences->Android